# Unhide Ribbon strips

Tags: configuration, content-editor, sitecore-client

I have managed to hide all ribbon strips by right clicking on ribbon and un checking them.

I have zero strips now, on the ribbon and so, ribbon is hidden. I cannot able to get them back.

[image: Content editor with out ribbon]

I have tried:

- Application Pool Recycle
- Reset to default settings in control panel

Could anyone have suggestions on how to get back the ribbon in sitecore8.2

Comment: Is there anything related in web browser console or in Sitecore logs?

Comment: No, nothing related to ribbon.

Comment: have you tried clearing the browser cache?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely a bug in Sitecore 8.2, as earlier versions of Sitecore 8 prevent you from removing the last strip from the ribbon, as can be see in the following screenshot:

[image]

#### Resolving the Issue

I suggest that you try to work around the issue by opening up Chrome Dev Tools (via F12 in your chrome browser) or Firebug (or whatever Mozilla calls it these days; via F12 in FireFox), and search for the (div) element with `id="Ribbon"`. If it is there, update it so that it has a reasonable `width` and `height` and make sure that it is set to `display: block` (all via CSS), in order to make it visible. Then *right-click* the element and the Context Menu should appear, allowing you to add back one or more ribbon strips.

If you are unable to find the (div) element with `id="Ribbon"` then try doing the same thing for the (div) element with `id="RibbonPanel"`. That one should render no matter what (even if it isn't displaying, due to content/CSS/etc).

If you still cannot fix the issue, try going into the User Manager, selecting your user and clicking the "Reset Settings" button. I have not tested this one myself, but it may work, as well.

[image]