# Sitecore ribbon doesn't show up

Tags: content-editor, ribbon

I am running Sitecore 8.0 on my development machine but I am not seeing the ribbon in the Content Editor anymore. I haven't made any drastic changes to my environment in the last week, except minor code changes to layouts/renderings.

I'm also not seeing any Javascript errors in Fiddler or Chrome console.

The issue is not with collapsed ribbon either. The ribbon appears with full height and width but doesn't show anything.

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Try to clean cache or open the instance in different browsers.

Comment: Do you have the same? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32863577/sitecore-8-ribbons-missing-from-toolbar

Comment: http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3281/unhide-ribbon-strips/3283

Comment: sitecore logs showing anything ?

Comment: Nope, nothing in the sitecore logs.

Comment: Please check following
1. Clear browser cache
2. Clear Sitecore Cache
3. Click Ribbon Toggle Arrow
4. Check about your role and permission 5. Check Ribbon control in Core Database

Comment: Please add a screenshot - is it just missing icons or the chunks/commands themselves are missing? If the former, could be write permissions in temp/app_data; if the latter could be an odd permissions problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your ribbon is still not displayed with 'toggle', you have to check the 'sc_lang' querystring in the URL. it should '?sc_lang=en' by default.

Answer (score -1):

Please check toggle ribbon at right side[image]

Comment: I knew this was going to be added as an answer .

Comment: Then you should have mentioned this too in your question.. This is most common cause so it always worth to start from the basic cause while giving the error. People try to help so you should also respect each attempt.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean it as a slight. But that is not the problem I'm facing. I've updated my question accordingly.